# Using Java to Send Multiple Mass Emails

Tags: java, email

I am needing to do some automatic email sending daily on a daily basis to say...for the sake of simplicity 1000 messages. What is the best way to accomplish this using java?

The plan of action right now is to basically just run a loop and send the messages one by one. Should I be taking a more complex approach using multiple threads, or somehow batching messages? I admit I am a total noob when it comes to managing email so I am more or less just looking for some suggestions to get me started.

Comment: Even though this is only about the technical part: Have though about the social part, i.e. "I don't want to be blacklisted?". Most ISPs will complain/shut you down if you mass-mail, and doing so may land you on email blacklists. Talk to your ISP before trying this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JavaMail, you can open a mail `Session` and send all your `MimeMessage` (as many as you want) and when you're done, close the `Session`. No need to keep opening a session, send a message and close.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm

Here is a simple exampe of JavaMail API as well.

Comment: So simply building an array, looping through it and sending one by one is the best option? The entire time keeping the session open. Is this how apps like mailchimp go about sending their messages?

Comment: There's probably also error handling strategies. Obviously you want to continue if one of the mail jobs failed but you also want to be able to keep track which ones failed.

Comment: Ideally, one musn't do session management. If you can send many emails in the one session, do so. Continously managing session is exhaustive, having to always open socket, send, close, and doing it again. How you deal with problematic sending and errors should be looked at as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are some helpful libraries out there, for example the [Apache Commons Email project](http://commons.apache.org/email/) (find [examples here](http://commons.apache.org/email/userguide.html)).

I wouldn't overly concern yourself about multiple threads unless performance is an issue, which is normally isn't for batch email jobs.